# Microsoft Surface Book 2 - "Clear" bar at top of screen in Windows Apps

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-edge, microsoft-surface

Encountering a strange recurring issue involving a Microsoft Surface Book 2.

When any Microsoft applications are full screen (ex: Windows Explorer, Settings, Office Suite, Edge), an occasional display error will occur. Approximately 1 inch horizontal of the full screen app will appear as clear, meaning it displays the desktop in that area, and even the desktop icons which can be interacted with.

This does not occur with any third party applications, such as Adobe, design software, Chrome, etc. This is also not limited to only Metro Apps but all Microsoft applications. This includes the x86 version of Office 365.

The issue does not occur if the application is windowed and stretched to cover most of the desktop (in an attempt to resemble a full screen experience).

I have attempted the following:

```
Microsoft Updates
Office Full Reinstall
sfc /scannow
"Sideloaded" the latest Intel HD Graphics Chipset and Control Panel - Set to Scale Full Screen - Override Application Settings
Windows Repair via MS Surface Diagnostic Toolkit
```

Thinking contacting MS Support to validate whether or not this is a hardware issue, or a clean reinstall is my next option, but looking for any other potential solutions.

Comment: Could someone with permissions add a "Microsoft-surface-book" tag, if you feel this is a relevant category to have?

Comment: We don't need a tag specific to the Surface Book.  The current `Microsoft-Surface` tag is more then enough.

Comment: Noted. I only ask because I saw tags for many Surface Pro models while entering tags, and thought this may be helpful.